# Imagens adicionadas com tinymce não respeitam div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tinymce

Fiz um que pequeno plugin de upload de arquivos que é integrado ao tinymce, mas quando adiciono imagens pelo tinymce elas não respeitam a div. Como posso arrumar isso? Vi que o tinymce adiciona tamanhos em pixel fixos, seria legal se ele adicionasse as imagens com style max-width e max-height mas não sei onde alterar o código html que ele gera.